# remove space line in refactor xml in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

how remove space in tag in xml layout?
i used **command + option + L** but not working

[image]

Comment: Did you just update the studio ?

Comment: android studio 3.0.1

Comment: Did you updated the studio or not !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> File -> Setting -> Editor -> Select XML -> Other Tab

chnage **`keep blank line = 0`**

like this

[image]

Than just use  like this  will work fine

Win

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Linux:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac:

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>